# multiple networks sharing variables

Tags: tensorflow

I am just getting started with Tensorflow and have a question about sharing variables.

I am running two neural nets simultaneously, but I want them both to share the weights and biases. My cost function will be a combination of the two networks. I'd like to use tf.layers.dense. Will this code result in the shared nature that I am looking for?

```
def NN_function(x1):
    x1 =  tf.layers.dense(x1,20, reuse=True,name="name1")
    x2 =  tf.layers.dense(x1,10, reuse=True,name="name2")
    x3 =  tf.layers.dense(x2,5, reuse=True,name="name3")
    output =  tf.layers.dense(x3,2, reuse=True,name="nam4")
    return output



pred_1 = NN_function(input_1)

pred_2 = NN_function(input_2)


costNN = tf.add(tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits= pred_1,
                                                                   labels=ply_2)),
            (alpha * tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits= pred_2,
                                                                            labels=PLy_1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to construct your layers under a consistent [variable scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope). The variable scope just augments the name of the variable, while allowing you the flexibility of choosing to reuse the variables.

```
def NN_function(x1):
    with tf.variable_scope('NN_func', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        x1 =  tf.layers.dense(x1,20, reuse=True,name="name1")
        x2 =  tf.layers.dense(x1,10, reuse=True,name="name2")
        x3 =  tf.layers.dense(x2,5, reuse=True,name="name3")
        output =  tf.layers.dense(x3,2, reuse=True,name="nam4")
        return output
```